# Android - ListView Item not changing its state

Tags: android, listview, background, selector, drawable

I'm currently facing a problem with background drawables on ListView Items.
I have a ListView XML, an Item XML, and a Drawable XML for the differents states that one item can have.

The problem is that when I click or press one of the item nothing changes visually, but the click works because the onItemClick() method I overrided is called and its code executed... Its like I didn't set the @background parameter !

layout/my_activity.xml (which contains the listview) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include ... />

    <include ... />

    <View
        ... />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewPacks"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="@color/blue_vdark"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

layout/listview_item_a.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/listview_item_a_d"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        ... />

    <TextView
        ... />

    <TextView
        ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

drawable/listview_item_a_d.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true"><shape>
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#bbbbbb" android:startColor="#e9e9e3" />
        </shape></item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true"><shape>
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#ecca2e" android:startColor="#f9f7c9" />
        </shape></item>
    <item><shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/gray_dark" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an adapter with my ListView and the problem was I changed my views' background in the getView method so I think the selector was drawn behind, or maybe not drawn at all. Anyway I just removed those lines of code and now it works fine, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

First, there is no persistent selected or focused state in touchmode.

You can get around this by using `state_activated`.

You can achieve this by setting the choice mode for the list to single or multiple (the default is none).

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Then use the activated state in your selector XML:

```
<item android:state_activated="true">
    <shape>   
        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#bbbbbb" droid:startColor="#e9e9e3" />   
    </shape>
</item>
```

Note that `state_activated` is for API 11+... for previous versions I believe you would have to go with an array in a custom adapter to keep track of the selected state and use that to set the background color/drawable in your adapter `getView` method.

Comment: Thanks, but it was not the problem.
I have an adapter with my ListView and the problem was I changed my views' backgound in the getView method so I think the selector was drawn behind, or maybe not drawn at all.

Anyway I juste removed those lines of code and now it works fine, thanks !